# Bucle en array map()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-hooks

Estoy implementando un calendario en react native con expo,el problema se basa en que quiero traer una fecha de la BD en firebase recorrerla y así marcar un evento en el calendario para esto uso:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: "",
      usuarios: [],
     };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref("DatosCli/")
          .on("child_added", (data) => {
            var datos = data.val();
            var usuariosTemp = this.state.usuarios;
            datos.key = data.key;
            usuariosTemp.push(datos);
            this.setState({ usuarios: usuariosTemp });
          });
      }


      cargarDatos = async () => {
    var userTemp = new Array();
    var data = await firebase.database().ref("/DatosCli").once("value");

    data.forEach((child) => {
      var user = child.val();
      user.key = child.key;
      userTemp.push(user);
    });
     this.setState({ usuarios: userTemp });
    };
```

y en el return - aquí es donde esta generando el error.
Justo en la linea donde está el `state.map`

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          {this.state.usuarios.map((usuarioTemp) => (
          <CalendarList
            markedDates={{
              [usuarioTemp.date]: {
                selected: true,
                disableTouchEvent: true,
                selectedColor: "orange",
                selectedTextColor: "red",
              },
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

En ocasiones anteriores había recorrido la bd pero nunca de esta forma, no sé si está bien o hay otra forma mejor.
La librería de calendario es: https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

Comment: Creo que el problema esta dentro del CalendarList. Le estas pasando una función (map) al componente que devuelve distintos markedDates={{}}. Podes probar haciendo markedDates={ // y aca adentro la fucion que devuelva los objetos de la forma [usuarioTemp.date]: {
              selected: true,
              disableTouchEvent: true,
              selectedColor: "orange",
              selectedTextColor: "red",
            }}

Comment: De paso te recomiendo otra librería por si queres probar: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/date-time-picker/

Comment: parece que por ahí van los tiros, intente lo que dice pero no sirve aun..voy a seguir intentado a ver que pasa..

Comment: Avance!,logre que se marcara la fecha que llega de la bd en el calendario colocando la funcion map fuera del CalendarList y el markedDates como me digiste, PERO la poner la funcion map fuera provoca que el calendario se repita muchas veces,es decir si hay 2 fechas 1 va a estar en 1 calendario y la otra fecha en otro calendario,@NachoZullo

Comment: habra que ver de que forma se puede acomodar para que solo genere un calendarioy que tenga multiples fechas en el

Comment: Podrias actualizar la pregunta con ese código? Asi te puedo ayudar mejor

Comment: listo,@NachoZullo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110360/discussion-between-nacho-zullo-and-fabianmeneses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queria tener una lista de fechas marcadas y no una lista de componentes calendario,al momento de hacer la pregunta habia un blucle de componentes calendario por cada fecha que habia.

Para solucionarlo se creo un objeto de `markedDates` usando la funcion forEach que recorre la base de datos y despues se pasa como apoyo al `CalendarList`

```
render() {
    const markedDates = {};
this.state.usuarios.forEach((usuarioTemp) => {
    markedDates[usuarioTemp.date] = {
        selected: true,
        disableTouchEvent: true,
        selectedColor: "orange",
        selectedTextColor: "red",
     };
});
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      
    <CalendarList markedDates={markedDates} />
        
       
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Que se realizo, podrìas agregar una explicaciòn, revisa [answer], saludos.